# Was worship of 3 times mentioned in Rig Veda III.4.2, a precursor to performing of Sandhyavandana 3 times a day?

Tags: rig-veda, agni, vayu

Rig Veda [III.4.2](https://archive.org/details/RigVedaSanhitaByHHWilsonVol2/page/n231), dedicated to **Āprīs**, says as follows:

> यं देवासस्त्रिरहन्नायजन्ते दिवे-दिवे वरुणो मित्रो अग्निः | सेमं यज्ञं
>   मधुमन्तं कर्धी नस्तनूनपाद घर्तयोनिं विधन्तम ||
>
> yaṃ devāsastrirahannāyajante dive-dive varuṇo mitro aghniḥ | semaṃ
>   yajñaṃ madhumantaṃ kṛdhī nastanūnapād ghṛtayoniṃ vidhantam ||
>
> **Tanūnapāt** whom the deities - **MITRA, VARUNA and AGNI**, worship daily thrice a day, render this our sacred rain-engendering sacrifice
>   productive of water.

The translation is of **H.H. Wilson**.

---

***[tanun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vayu)*** indicates the wind or vAyu

[**napāt**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/napat) indicates grand son or descendant

So it might indicate **grandson or descendant of vAyu**.

---

My questions are:

1. Who is the ***Tanūnapāt*** whom the deities - MITRA, VARUNA and AGNI, worship daily thrice a day?
2. Was worship of 3 times mentioned in this mantra, a precursor to performing of **Sandhyavandana** 3 times a day?

Comment: Google search shows Tanūnapāt is a manifestation of Agni. I am sure you must have searched this. Do you find this explanation unsatisfactory?

Comment: I checked this. My doubt is why Agni worships himself 3 times. Please check translation again.@I will close your question

Comment: Check Griffith translation. Seems to make more sense.

Comment: Yes I checked before posting the question. Let me wait for others response:-) @I will close your question

Comment: While you wait for a response, Yaska might give a clue.

Comment: Do you have link to that clue? @I will close your question

Comment: Please check - https://archive.org/details/nighantuniruktao00yaskuoft  I would have checked myself if I were using my laptop. It is very tedious to check in mobile. By the way, ctrl F might work ( I am not sure though)

Comment: This seems better - https://www.globalgreyebooks.com/nighantu-and-the-nirukta-ebook.html  Download here and go to pg no. 549 in pdf. Searchable file.

Comment: @Iwillcloseyourquestion: It gives the meaning of descendant.  However, meaning is still not understandable.

Comment: It also gives Agni as one of the meanings. Please check.

Comment: @Iwillcloseyourquestion: Yes, Agni was an indirect meaning.  Still Why Agni should worship himself, along with Varuna and Mitra? Either HH Wilson got it wrong or something is missing?

Comment: Griffith translation does not say Agni worships Tanunapat.

Comment: May its says of arghyam of water should be given thrice a day with your hand (astha) the pada chedam is done with hand unto pada of the svatiru that is vishnu.. or sun rays..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In [Bṛhaddevatā (page.77)](https://archive.org/stream/bhaddevat01univgoog#page/n96/mode/2up), it was mentioned that Agni is also called as **Tanūnapāt**
2. Sandhyavandanam [was used to be done 2 times a day](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37636/3869), as sandhya - twilight time occurs twice daily.  Subsequently, another time at midday was added at a later date.