# Had the worship of GOD been changed from 2 times to 3 times a day in the ancient Rig vedic period?

Tags: rig-veda, vishwamitra, bhrigu

[Rig Veda II.8.3,](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv02008.htm)composed by the sage from Bhrigu family, eulogises AGNI as follows:

> य उ शरिया दमेष्वा दोषोषसि परशस्यते | यस्य वरतं न मीयते ||
>
> Who for his glory is extolled at ***eve and morning*** in our homes,
> Whose statute is inviolate;

This indicates that by the time this mantra was composed, AGNI had been worshiped ***twice a day*** only.

---

However, Rig Veda III.4.2, composed by Sage Viswamitra and dedicated to Āprīs, says that the deities - MITRA, VARUNA and AGNI, ***worship*** [daily **thrice a day**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/37350/3869).

[Many scholars inferred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigveda#Mandalas) that 2nd to 7th Mandalas of Rig Veda are the Oldest among the 10 Mandalas.

Even among 2nd to 7th Mandalas of Rig Veda, 2nd Mandala was the forerunner compared to 3rd Mandala.

---

My question is

- was there a shift **in number of times** of worshiping GOD, from the period in which  Rig Veda II.8.3 had been composed (**2 times a day**) to the period in which  Rig Veda III.4.2 had been composed (**3 times a day**)?