# Dharma sandeham

Tags: vedas, upanishads, dharma-shastras, sandhyavandanam

1:
I hear many people telling things like there is no need for women in periods to not work and be normal but sanatana dharmam strictly says women should not do any kind of work for those three day.

2:
Anyone wearing the sacred thread has to do sandhya vandanam 3 times a day at stipulated time but many people do not follow this sighting time as a reason. Many can perform sandhya vandanam in morning and evening but the noons procedure can be done at evening after performing the evening procedure but many people do not do this.

There are many such things that we change according to our convince or comfort.

I feel that if you are following something you should abide by the rules and regulations that the system has, sanatana dharmam has many guidelines that on can modify according to their convince and may that we have to strictly abide by. Modifying the most basic things would result in loss of the essence of the dharmam.

Am I thinking in the right direction or is there something that I am missing out on please think and guide me.

Comment: Hi, *Namaskaaram* !! A very warm Welcome to HSE!! Please visit [FAQ Index for HSE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/478/faq-index-for-hinduism-stack-exchange) and go please try to go through it properly. Have an enriching journey ahead.

Comment: You may refer to [THIS ANSWER for your 1st Question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21014/what-is-the-overall-take-of-hinduism-on-menstruation)  &  [THIS ANSWER](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21349/what-is-the-prayachitta-for-not-doing-sandhyavandanam-regularly) and [THIS ANSWER](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27329/why-do-we-need-to-do-three-time-prayingtrikal-sandhya) for your 2nd Question.

Comment: You're correct in your thinking. People bend the rules according to their interest in following dharma.